# SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function in Google Cloud Speech-to-Text

Tags: node.js, terminal

Bit of an amateur in both node.js and Google cloud tools. I've taken this code to attempt to transcribe a piece of audio from my Google Cloud bucket. When I run `node index.js` in the terminal I just get *SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function*. I realise that it means I need an async function. But how can I turn this entire file into a command that can be run from the terminal successfully?

```js
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

// Creates a client
const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
 */
const gcsUri = 'gs://anitomaudiofiles/911isnojoke.mp3';
const encoding = 'MP3';
const sampleRateHertz = 16000;
const languageCode = 'en-US';

const config = {
  encoding: encoding,
  sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
  languageCode: languageCode,
};

const audio = {
  uri: gcsUri,
};

const request = {
  config: config,
  audio: audio,
};

// Detects speech in the audio file. This creates a recognition job that you
// can wait for now, or get its result later.
const [operation] = await client.longRunningRecognize(request);
// Get a Promise representation of the final result of the job
const [response] = await operation.promise();
const transcription = response.results
  .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
  .join('\n');
console.log(`Transcription: ${transcription}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't write `await operation.promise()` outside of an async function. If you want to use await it should be inside a function.

```
(async runOperations() {
  const [operation] = await client.longRunningRecognize(request);
  // Get a Promise representation of the final result of the job

  const [response] = await operation.promise();
  const transcription = response.results
      .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
      .join('\n');
  console.log(`Transcription: ${transcription}`);
})();
```

This you can put inside your file and run `node <filename.js>` to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in an async function:

```
// earlier code here

async function main() {
  const [operation] = await client.longRunningRecognize(request);
  const [response] = await operation.promise();
  const transcription = response.results
    .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
    .join('\n');
  console.log(`Transcription: ${transcription}`);
}

main()
```